# Micronaut + Intellij = is clean compilation required?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

Is clean compilation required, if I am using Intellij and Micronaut with lombok and micronaut data annotation processors? Java 14.

It seems for me, any code change is not visible during next app run without clean compilation or no?

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: no, latest maven

Comment: It depends in part on how you are launching the application.

Comment: @JeffScotBrown - just Run Application button in Idea.

Comment: I also face similar issues. When re running `@MicronautTests` sometimes it ends up saying 'path taken' or the other way around, it's not able to inject certain `@Singleton` objects. The only thing that works is deleting the gradle and build folders

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you consider a *clean compilation*. If you're talking about Intelli-Sense, then even clean build will not guarantee to not emit false-positives. If you're talking about an actual compilation process (the actual errors you get when trying to compile the project), then yes, it is a known *bug*<sup>1</sup> that the combination of those two produces the unexpected, incorrect errors.

---

<sup>1</sup>or rather, an *incovenience* based on the inability to correctly correctly coexist.

Comment: I mean, controller with new method on path /newPath is still not responding after adding it to the codebase and pressing green triangle in Idea.